How can I automatically select a passkey in Chrome's passkey popup?
I'm using Chrome on a mac to login to a website using a passkey. When I arrive at the login screen, Chrome pops up this window for me to choose a passkey with the prompt: Use your passkey for website.com.
Is there any way to bypass this and always use a specific key automatically?
I actually only have one key for the website, so it's surprising that it prompts me at all.


Does this post help?
